# No. of bijections from $A$ to $A$ provided that no element of $A$ is mapped to itself.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find the number of bijections provided that no element of $A$ is mapped to itself. The set has 5 elements

I know the total number of bijections are $5!$, and I need to find the number of bijections with 5 elements mapped to themselves, 4 elements, 3 elements, 2 elements, and 1 element. I understand that the number of bijections with 5 elements and 4 elements mapped to themselves is 1, the number of bijections with 3 elements mapped to themselves is $\binom{5}{3}$.

However, when I see the answer on Internet, the number of bijections with 2 elements mapped to themselves is $2\binom{5}{2}$.

Where does that 2 comes from?

Thanks.

Comment: Once you fix the 2 elements that will map to themselves, in how many ways the rest 3 can map to each other?

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks @TonyPizza.

Comment: See [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).